# Which one is the correct normal vector?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $\alpha$ be a curve parametrised by arc length $\alpha(s)=(x(s),y(s))$. So the tangent to this curve is a unit vector $t(s)=\bigl(\dot x(s),\dot y(s)\bigr)$.

My question is which one is the normal vector:
$n(s)=\bigl(-\dot y(s),\dot x(s)\bigr)$ OR $n(s)=\bigl(\dot y(s),-\dot x(s)\bigr)$ ?

Does it depend on the orientation? If the curve has a positive orientation, which normal vector does it have? How can we tell?

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the orientation *and* on your convention. There isn't one "natural" choice of normal direction and so different authors might choose different conventions.

If I *had* to bet I would guess $(-\dot y, \dot x)$ so that the 90-degree rotation operator agrees with multiplication by $i$ in the complex plane, but I wouldn't place a large wager. Check your definition.